# Scrollable Content with fixed header without using the JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, jtableheader

I want to fix the header of my content so it does not scroll down with the content.
Is it possible to do it with a, and if yes, could you please shed some light as to how I can go about implementing it without using a JTable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JScrollPane` has

```
public void setRowHeader(JViewport rowHeader)
```

See e.g. http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Scrollpaneruler.htm

Comment: Use `setColumnHeaderView` to get the header above the content and you don't have to make your own view port.

Comment: @ Walter Laan You are right! Both row and column headers are possible.

Comment: Thanx a lot for the info @ StanislavL, I appreciate it, @ Walter thank you, exactly what I needed, it really worked wonders.  Wish I could mark it as useful but I dont have enough reputation points. Once again thank you guys.

Answer (score 2):

- [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) in the [JScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) has [TableHeader fixed in Rectangle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#width)
- there are three (standard)ways where isn't `TableHeader` fixed on some `Point`

  1. `JTable` in the `JScrollPane` is layed by som of [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) (notice depends of type of `LayoutManager` or `area` ) into resiziable `Container`
  2. `JTable` in the `JScrollPane` could be draggable
  3. `JTable` has resizable `ColumnModel`